# EntityFramework: Is it possible to map two different columns to the same entity/model that follows the same practices?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm building an application that takes data from an existing table, and then splits it into multiple entities, that follow specific trends. It is for a letting agent that manages multiple different agencies. One such shared entity that I have identified is the Address, shared by Landlord, Letting Agent and the actual property all of which share the properties below:

```
public class Address 
    {
        public string HouseNumber
        public string FlatPosition
        public string AddressLine
        public string Town
        public string County
        public string Postcode
    }
```

In the giant table, they follow the above schema, but are specified with the relevant noun in front e.g.
"LandlordHouseNumber etc., PropertyHouseNumber etc., LettingAgentHouseNumber etc.,"

Is it possible to take the data from the table, and instantiate with the address class whilst being able to distinguish the entity they represent? Or will I need to have an address class for each?

EDIT:

[image: Table heading structure]

Comment: Include an example table definition and the entity definitions you'd like that transformed into.  I think what you want done can be accomplished via complex types but we need more details

Comment: @Moho I've added the table headings, I've had to exclude the data due to GDPR.

Comment: Is this for exporting to CSV?

Comment: No it's for displaying on a front end. Basically is a small application that allows users to see who lives where, who the landlord is etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suspected, what you want is to define a `Complex Type` for the address then map the properties to the appropriate columns.

```
public class Address 
{
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string FlatPosition { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}

public YourEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // or whatever you use
    // other properties

    // complex type properites
    public Address LandlordAddress { get; set; }
    public Address LandlordAgentAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Then configure in your `DbContext`:

```
protected void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    // configure like an entity but use .ComplexType<>()
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<Address>()
        // e.g. set max size of one of the properties
        .Property( a => a.Postcode )
        .HasMaxLength( 10 );
    // etc.

    // map properties to columns if you don't want to use default naming convention
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>()
        .Property( yet => yet.LandlordAddress.Postcode )
        .HasColumnName( "LandlordPostcode" );

    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntityType>()
        .Property( yet => yet.LandordAgentAddress.Postcode )
        .HasColumnName( "LandlordAgentPostcode" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Fold in the database

You could create a view, or create a query, that folds these 3x columns into a sensible one column.

### 2. Fold upon retrieval

#### 2a Linq-to-sql

```
//Model
public class Address 
    {
        public string AHouseNumber 
        public string BHouseNumber 
        public string CHouseNumber 
(...)
```

You could do a simple concat:

```
await db.Addresses
  .Select( a=> new { Address = AHouseNumber + BHouseNumber + CHouseNumber } )
  .ToListAsync();
```

#### 2b. Run custom query

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to use one model class for your situation. However, you could create a common interface for all of your `Address` models:

```cs
public interface IAddress
{
    string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    string FlatPosition { get; set; }
    string AddressLine { get; set; }
    string Town { get; set; }
    string County { get; set; }
    string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Then add your model classes like this:

```cs
public class LandLordAddress : IAddress
{
    [Column("LandLordHouseNumber")]
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This way, you will at least be able to write more generic code to operate on instances of these classes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! By labelling the Column name at the top, and then connecting to an already existing table - would that still bring in the relative data? I've been quite confused about how EF actually migrates already existing data into an application.

Comment: Yes, the [`ColumnAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute?view=netframework-4.8) maps your model property to a database table column of a different name. It comes in handy quite often if you're using the database first approach and your naming conventions differ between your C# project and your database.